# How can I modify the size of table in a mysql table? size in MB

Tags: mysql

I need to change the default size that comes by the table, query some of MySQL to change the table size in MB

Comment: Can you elaborate further. Are you referring to the max size based on OS ie  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-size-limit.html

Comment: What do you mean? There's generally no "default size" for a table. The size is entirely based on the amount of data you put into it.